# Using discord.py on linux I get the error 'Bot' object has no attribute 'join_voice_channel'

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, discord.py, attributeerror

Code in question:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
    async def yt(ctx, url):
    author = ctx.message.author
    voice_channel = author.voice.channel
    vc = await bot.join_voice_channel(voice_channel)

    player = await vc.create_ytdl_player(url, before_options="-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5")
    player.start()
```

Error I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/wilkins30/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 79, in wrapped
        ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
    File "OverBot.py", line 286, in one
        vc = await bot.join_voice_channel(voice_channel)
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'join_voice_channel'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/wilkins30/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 863, in invoke
        await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
    File "/home/wilkins30/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 727, in invoke
        await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
    File "/home/wilkins30/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 88, in wrapped
        raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: 
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'join_voice_channel'
```

I am running python3 in Ubuntu 19 on a google virtual machine. So I have looked all over and could only find this [thread](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/1130) talking about the issue but solutions there didn't work. This worked for me in a windows environment. which lead me to believe it was opus not being loaded so I reinstalled that and verified that it was being successfully called. I have also created a fresh instance of the virtual machine to no avail as well. I'm sort of lost at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The newer versions of `discord.py`, referred to as the `rewrite` branch, no longer has `client.join_voice_channel()`. This has been changed to `VoiceChannel.connect`. See documentation [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html?highlight=join_voice_channel#migrating-1-0-voice).

> Before:
>
> ```
> vc = await client.join_voice_channel(channel)
> player = vc.create_ffmpeg_player('testing.mp3', after=lambda: print('done'))
> player.start()
>
> player.is_playing()
> player.pause()
> player.resume()
> player.stop()
> # ...
> ```
>
> After:
>
> ```
> vc = await channel.connect()
> vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('testing.mp3'), after=lambda e: print('done', e))
> vc.is_playing()
> vc.pause()
> vc.resume()
> vc.stop()
> # ...
> ```

As there are many changes in the new version, you may have to spend some time to migrate your code. If you would like to install the older version of `discord.py`, referred to as the `async` branch, then you can do so by running the following command on your linux machine.

```
sudo python3 -m pip install discord.py==0.16.12 --force-reinstall
```

Comment: You were completely right. i'm not sure why pip installed the older version on my windows machine but either way it works. Though for anyone who sees this in the future and is trying to play YouTube audio you can use **youtube_dl** to download the video as an audio file and feed that into `discord.FFmpegPCMAudio()`

Comment: There's a basic voice example on the github that you can use to create a player that uses `youtube_dl` https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_voice.py