# In Discord.py - rewrite AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'voice_client_in'

Tags: python, discord.py

I have tried many things and googled alot but still can't figure out how to play music to a voice channel using discord.py-rewrite.

My code:

```
#playing music from a link
async def play_link(ctx,url):

    #joining user's voice channel
    await join_auth(ctx)

    #playing music
    voice = client.voice_client_in(ctx.guild) 
    player = await voice.create_ytdl_player(url)
    player.start()
```

It raises this error:

```
 File "C:\Users\Eugene\Desktop\Discord bot\Auto_music.py", line 207, in play_link
    voice = client.voice_client_in(ctx.guild)
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'voice_client_in'
```

Comment: what version of discordpy are you using? it looks like that method doesn't exist in the most recent version of [discordpy](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=voice_client_in&check_keywords=yes&area=default).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56539112/using-discord-py-on-linux-i-get-the-error-bot-object-has-no-attribute-join-vo/56540260#56540260

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example code on a music bot in the [Github](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_voice.py)

It's not the best but it'll work just fine.